# Can the Silence spell be cast on a character or object that can then be moved?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement, targeting, area-of-effect

A PC Cleric wants to cast the *silence* spell on one of the two PC Fighters in their party so that the Fighters can enter a room to kill orcs without having the noise of the battle alarm orcs in other rooms.

As long as the Cleric concentrates on the spell and doesn't engage in other activities that would stop concentration, is this ok?

What about casting it on an object that you move around or throw into the midst of a room to eliminate the noise from activity/battle?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but worth pointing out that very few activities outside of concentrating on a different spell would require the cleric to stop concentrating on it. Even casting other spells is fine, as long as the cast doesn't take longer than an action.

Comment: @Cubic: Failing a concentration check from taking damage would be the major one which justifies staying outside the room if that would be a total disaster, but yes, good point that the phrasing here makes it sound like concentration is really hard to maintain.

Comment: Mcjeffs, I've rejected an edit I belive you tried to suggest. Firstly, you should register a full account (so you get login credentials) and get your [accounts merged](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). Then you can show appreciation for the answer by accepting it (there'll be a checkmark). Also, if you have a new question please [ask it as such](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and feel free to link to this one if it helps with context.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### This won't work

Target of the [*silence*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/silence) spell is a point. It neither an object nor a creature:

> 20-foot-radius sphere centered on a point you choose within range

A point is fixed in space, [unless your DM says otherwise](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/134302/). If a spell can be cast on an object so its effect moves with this object, its description explicitly says so. See the [*darkness*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/darkness) spell for example:

> If the point you choose is on an object you are holding or one that isn't being worn or carried, the darkness emanates from the object and moves with it.

See also [Can the area of effect of a spell be moved only if the description specifies so?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71122/)

**That doesn't mean the spell is useless** in this case. You still can cast the spell into the middle of the room as soon as the fighters burst through the door to achieve the desired effect. Readying a spell is a classic way to do that.

Comment: @candied and Peter We have quite a few questions already on frames if reference if you want some interesting reads: [1](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/69917) [2](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/134302) [3](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/161613) [4](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/102339) [5](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/148614) [6](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/168220) [7](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/112699) [8](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/107220). Also remember that this isn't a discussion forum and comments are meant to help improve posts. Feel free to discuss in [chat] though

Comment: @Medix2 well researched links. Those are better then what's offered here. I meant only to inspire edits.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109138/discussion-on-answer-by-enkryptor-can-the-silence-spell-be-cast-on-a-character-o).